# How to apply the loading spinner on a Dynamiclly loaded images in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, firebase

I have to apply the spinner on a dynamically loaded image from the firebase and i am using directive for the loading the spinner but its not working properly spinner is not show on image load

```js
//create the module for our application
var app= angular.module("shoppingApp", []);
 app.directive('loading', function () {
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace:true,
        template: '<div class="loading"><img src="http://www.nasa.gov/multimedia/videogallery/ajax-loader.gif" width="20" height="20" />LOADING...</div>',
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {
          scope.$watch('loading', function (val) {
              if (val)
                  $(element).show();
              else
                  $(element).hide();
          });
        }
      }
  })
  
//getProductData FUNCTION FOR GET THE LIST OF THE PRODUCRS AND CALL INTIALLY AFTER PAGE LOAD
 $scope.productArray   = []; 
 $scope.getProductData = function(callback, offset, limit) {
  //USER FOR SHOW THE LOADER IF LIST IS GET FROM DB
  $scope.loading = true; firebase.database().ref("sellerProduct").once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
  var value = snapshot.val();
   $scope.productArray = objToArray(value);
  
   //USED FOR DIABLE THE LAODER IF RESPONSE IS RECEIVED
   $scope.loading = false;
  });
 }
```

```html
<div class="hover-div" ng-right-click>
 <loading>
   <img id="myImage" ondragstart="return false;"  
    class="imageSet" src="{{list.ImageURL}}" width="100%">
  </loading>
</div>
```

?

Answer (score 1):

you don't need whole directive for this. Just create that img element maybe with that div and put ng-show="loading" on that element - given your code I think it should work because you set loading to true before promise and you set it to false after which should work so your html:

```
<div class="hover-div" ng-right-click>
    <img id="myImage" ondragstart="return false;" class="imageSet" src="{{list.ImageURL}}" width="100%">
    <div ng-show="loading" class="loading" />
      <img src="https://www.nasa.gov/multimedia/videogallery/ajax-loader.gif" width="20" height="20" />LOADING...
     </div>
</div>
```

and then just use css something like:

```
.loading {
  background-color: black;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

might not work though depending on your parent element css (.hover-div)

Also if you really want directive - put loading binding on scope and just put my code (.loading div) in your template. You don't need any watchers it will work just position it properly.

```
app.directive('loading', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace:true,
    scope:{
      loading: '='
    },
    template: '<div ng-show="loading" class="loading"><img src="https://www.nasa.gov/multimedia/videogallery/ajax-loader.gif" width="20" height="20" />LOADING...</div>',
    link: function (scope, element, attr) {

    }
  }
```

});

and html wow, now this directive initialization looks confusing but should work:

```
<div class="hover-div" ng-right-click>
        <img id="myImage" ondragstart="return false;" class="imageSet" src="{{list.ImageURL}}" width="100%">
        <loading loading='loading'>
    </div>
```

Comment: Sir its not working properly, spinner are not apply on the image it will be apply on a whole page ?

Comment: here's experimentation fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pegla/j215opy3/2/ It is bit primitive example but you will need to show me your css to style it properly.

Comment: now its working sir  thank you,sir please tell m how this directive working inside ?

Comment: No problem, current scope (one of directive) is binding your 'loading' from other scope through 2 way binding, if one changes other will change as well. ng-show will show div if loading property on previous scope equals to true, since they are basically same value it will work as if it was on same scope. Now loading directive is overlaying with css, sets position to absolute - over the element (and left and top value to 0) then it's all about setting right width and height, z-index property will make it overlay. You can accept/upvote the answer if it was helpful, thanks.

Comment: Thank you sir, this information are really helpul for me.

Comment: no problem, but can you please make my answer as accepted, and upvote if it was helpful, since that's how it should work.

Comment: sir i need you help in another issue can you help ?

Comment: Well I can but not here's this thread is getting too long, post another question, I will find it.